# Update typical json in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have table where one column contains json format where I'm trying to update the column but no luck.Please look into given query, any help will be appreciable.

Query

```
    update data_file
  set json_data = jsonb_set(json_data::jsonb,  '{"tables","li_daily_sales_ll"}'::text[],
      json_extract_path(json_data ->'tables', 'li_daily_sales_ll' )::jsonb, '{ada}', jsonb_build_object( '{adapartialcurrentperiod}','202001') ,true)
      where data_file_id = 475;
```

input json

```
{
    "tables": {
        "li_daily_sales_ll": {
            "sourcedetails": {
                "sourceT": "Hive",
                "sourceconnection": "xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx",
                "duplicateCheck": null,
                "targetN": null,
                "partitionName": null
            },
            "ada": {
                "adatype": "Partial",
                "adatargettablename": "xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx",
                "adaprimarykeycols": null,
                "adafilter": null,
                "adahistorypartitioncols": "xxxxxxx",
                "adapartialcurrentperiod": 202003
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output Json

```
{
    "tables": {
        "li_daily_sales_ll": {
            "sourcedetails": {
                "sourceT": "Hive",
                "sourceconnection": "xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx",
                "duplicateCheck": null,
                "targetN": null,
                "partitionName": null
            },
            "ada": {
                "adatype": "Partial",
                "adatargettablename": "xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx",
                "adaprimarykeycols": null,
                "adafilter": null,
                "adahistorypartitioncols": "xxxxxxx",
                "adapartialcurrentperiod": 202001
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What the cast to `jsonb`? If the column contains JSON values, you should define it as `jsonb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be as simple as:

```sql
update data_file
  set json_data = jsonb_set(json_data::jsonb,
                            '{tables,li_daily_sales_ll,ada,adapartialcurrentperiod}'::text[],
                            '202001')
where data_file_id = 475;
```